# can I use grpcurl to test a stream endpoint

Tags: go, grpcurl

Is it possible to test a streaming grpc endpoint using the grpcurl client tool.  So far I have found [How to upload an image in chunks with client-side streaming gRPC using grpcurl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66034060/how-to-upload-an-image-in-chunks-with-client-side-streaming-grpc-using-grpcurl), however this was confusing, is there some other way to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

Pass `'@'` as the data string to invoke a stdin-based message stream.

For example:

```
grpcurl \
 -plaintext \
 -proto ./my_service.proto \
 -d '@' \
 host:port \
 Service/Method
```

Answer (score -1):

According to the documentation https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl you could do it

> grpcurl supports all kinds of RPC methods, including streaming
> methods. You can even operate bi-directional streaming methods
> interactively by running grpcurl from an interactive terminal and
> using stdin as the request body!